# Writing store updates back to server

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have read the Sencha tutorials, API, and forums for awhile but am hitting a brick wall. I have a mySQL/PHP backend that is storing a web application's data. I have the following Sench/ExtJS construct:

```
App.stores.user = new Ext.data.Store({
  model: 'User',
  proxy: new Ext.data.AjaxProxy({
      url: 'app/stores/scripts/connect.php',
      extraParams: {
          method:'user',
          user_id: 3
      },
      reader: {
          type:'json',
          root:'root'
      }
  }),
  autoLoad:true
});
```

Data is loaded into the store fine, but I have a form that directly updates a *User* instance.

```
App.controllers.account =  new Ext.Controller({
    save: function (options) {
        options.user.set(options.data);
        options.user.save(); // Generates error: Uncaught Error: You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.
    }
});
```

How can I successfully implement/hook the functions to write the dirty records back to the server? How is the request prepared and passed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Uptil Ext Js 3.3.1 the store needs to be configured with a `writer` when performing CRUD operations. It isn't needed for read only. That's why your store is loaded but you're getting an error during write operations. In your case you'll have to specify a `JsonWriter`. Also, if you're not using the store in a *restful* manner, then you'll also need to specify a `HttpProxy` object to tell the store at which url to publish the  create/update/delete on the `store`.

Check the docs for Ext 4. I should be something similar here too.

Comment: How do I specify an HttpProxy object for the store?